# LLVM module-level inliner `ModuleInlinerWrapperPass` usage

Tags: clang, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang

From reading the source code of LLVM in `lib/Transforms/IPO/Inliner.cpp` I found that LLVM designed the actual inliner pass as a CGSCC pass, and then there is `ModuleInlinerWrapperPass` that wraps around the CGSCC pass to do per-module inlining.

Peeking inside `PassBuilder.cpp`, I found the module-level inliner wrapper pass is typically run at the PGO-instrumentation stage (as part of the `addPGOInstrPipeline` pipeline), as well as the LTO stage.

I was interested in the differences between the CGSCC pass and the module-level pass and which one is scheduled earlier, so I added some LLVM_DEBUG statements to print from the initializer of the module-level pass. seems like by default `opt -O2` does not run the module-level inliner; instead, it runs the CGSCC pass quite early in the optimization pipeline.

My question is: When is the module-level inliner pass run in the optimization pipeline (if ever), and what is its relationship with the CGSCC inliner pass?

Comment: Seems like it's something introduced with the new PassManager. Running `clang -fexperimental-new-pass-manager` invokes the ModuleInlinerWrapperPass correctly. Still investigating what's the difference, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question boils down to the difference between the new PassManager and old PassManager in LLVM.

Essentially, there are two ways to write a pass: either we can use the new PassManager (with pass classes extending `PassInfoMixin<...>`) or use the legacy PassManager (with pass classes extending `ModulePass`/`CGSCCPass`/`FunctionPass`...).

The new PassManager uses the `PassBuilder` class to schedule passes into pipelines and then run the pipeline in the sequence it is scheduled. The `ModuleInlinerWrapperPass` is essentially a module-level wrapper pass in order for the new PassManager to schedule inliner into its existing module-level optimization pipeline.